# Why does fscanf work with fine without using the address of parameters 3+?

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-address

I am making a .obj loader in Objective-c and C, by following this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/) (pure c++). But I noticed that the function `fscanf()` runs fine for me even if you don't send it the memory address of the variables it going to set (sending the value only). Is there an explanation to this?

```
 Vec2 *uv;
 fscanf(file, "%f %f\n", uv.x, uv.y);
 [tempUVs addObject:uv];
```

Notice that parameters uv.x and uv.y have no ampersand.

Comment: This *can't* compile. `uv` is a pointer and you are using `uv.x` what would that be?

Comment: @JensGustedt: He got it all kinds of wrong. In the tutorial, `uv` is of type `glm::vec2`, and there *are* ampersands in the `fscanf()` call...

Comment: @Jens: It *can* compile: if `Vec2` is an Objective-C object type, then `uv.x` and `uv.y` could be [property accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior** when you do that.  Anything could happen -- it could crash, it could happen to run correctly, it could *appear* to run correctly while silently corrupting memory, or it could erase your hard drive.  Those are all allowed behaviors according to the language standard.

If you're compiling with a decent compiler, you can crank up your warning level (e.g. the `-Wall`, and maybe also `-Wextra -pedantic` using GCC or Clang), and it can warn you when you pass the wrong parameters to the `*scanf`/`*printf` family of functions.  Specifically, the [`-Wformat`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-264) option will warn for this sort of thing (`-Wformat` is included as part of `-Wall`).

Comment: What exactly is UB here?

Comment: @netcoder: In the linked tutorial, it's `&uv.x, &uv.y`. The OP "forgot" the ampersands, and is asking why it "works" nevertheless (for loose definitions of "working"). Chances are good that `uv.x, uv.y` are not of pointer type (couldn't tell at a glance as the tutorial doesn't list their definition), and thus, feeding them to `fscanf()` would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @netcoder writing a floating point value in a place that is supposed to be a pointer?

Comment: @netcoder, yes assuming that the components `x` (well of what `uv`, `*uv` ? ) are the floating points and not pointer to floating points. At least in the example of the link this seems to be the case.

Comment: @netcoder: If you didn't read the linked page, who's the one doing the assuming?

Comment: @DevSolar: I checked the linked page rapidly, but there's no definition of `Vec2` there either. So you're assuming that the code there is right... for all I know it could also be wrong: I have no clue how `Vec2` is defined.

Comment: @netcoder: glm::vec2 is an OpenGL datatype ("floating point vector").

Comment: @DevSolar: It's all a waste of time really. First of all, the program is ill-formed. Secondly, the OP references a type called `Vec2`, not `glm::vec2` or `vec2`. The question makes no sense in its current form because it just can't compile.

Comment: @netcoder: "The program is ill-formed"? OP didn't even *post* a program, he posted a (mistaken) code snippet. And you are tossing wisecracks at a well-done answer, without being of help to anyone.

Comment: @DevSolar: And you're being of help with who exactly? Screw this. If you want to argue with yourself, [do it in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22926/discussion-between-netcoder-and-devsolar).

Comment: The snippet might compile, if `Vec2` is an Object-C class type, in which case `uv.x` and `uv.y` could be [property accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW10).  However, even if it did compile, and even if the `x` and `y` properties were pointers (which would be very surprising), it's still UB because the `uv` instance is never initialized.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: Thanks for the complementary explanation. :)